# Command syntax for matlab function still generates output?

Tags: matlab

There are [two ways](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/syntax.html) to call functions in Matlab, the command syntax and function syntax.
I am viewing a code written by someone else in which there's a statement as follows in one .m file:

```
params=sys_params;
```

while sys_params is defined as a function in another .m file as:

```
function params=sys_params()
```

params happens to be a structure. 
What I wish to know is, if according to Matlab documentation, a command syntax cannot be used to output from a function, then how is the first statement working perfectly well?

Comment: Your second line of code is a function definition, i.e. the start of the function itself. Your first line of code *uses* that function. Neither of these use really use command syntax, since that's only relevant when there is an input argument...

Comment: Since sys_params was called without any arguments, it rendered itself to ambiguity since the calling was similar to how you'd call a function using command syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. The distinction between command and function syntax comes into play when arguments are passed.
2. The parentheses for calling a function in MATLAB are optional when calling with no arguments.  MATLAB will call the function without an invoking `()` unlike some other languages.

   One exception to this that comes to mind is that `()` is required to invoke a function handle/anonymous function.

From [Calling Functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/calling-functions.html):

> To call a function that does not require any inputs and does not return any outputs, type only the function name

The one ambiguous thing not explicitly told there is that assigning output of such a function call is perfectly valid.

---

I'll note that I don't really like that `()` is optional as it hides function calls at-first-glance.  Therefore, I try to use `()` as often as possible to make it clear I am invoking a function, so nearly all of my scripts start with `clc();clear();`.